# MYSQL PHP check a like statement on more one column at once

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have query I have came up with for a search bar. I know I can use OR to split the statement to check different columns:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE cats LIKE "%'.$s.'%" OR sub_cats LIKE "%'.$s.'%"');
```

But if I want to check more than 2 or three columns is the re a way doing something like this to speed things up a bit:

```
$query_string = explode('&&=',$_GET['q']);
    $db_str = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE name, cats, sub_cats, desc, brand ';
    for($x = 0; $x < count($query_string); $x++){
        $enc = mysql_real_escape_string($query_string[$x]);
        if($x == (count($query_string) -1)){
            $db_str .= 'LIKE "%'.$enc.'%"';
        }else{
            $db_str .= 'LIKE "%'.$enc.'%" ';
        }
    }
    $query = mysql_query($db_str);
```

I normally used POST for search bars but I fancy giving GET a go it looks more user friendly to me.

Comment: You most likely need [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) search.

Comment: Let's all say it together now... `Don't USE mysql; it's deprecated.  Switch to MYSQLI or PDO.`

Comment: @Sable Foste Did you mean Mysql is deprecated, use PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work like that, even [ignoring the deprecated API](http://www.php.net/mysql_query). You would need to do something like this:

```
$searchFields = ['name', 'cats', 'sub_cats', 'desc', 'brand'];
$searchTerm = mysql_real_escape_string($query_string[$x]);
$filters = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($field) use ($searchTerm) {
    return "$field LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'";
}, $searchFields));
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE '.$filters);
```

It's far from optimal though, and will quickly become slow as database and userbase grow. It is however exactly how for example phpMyAdmin implements its database-wide searches. If your database is larger than a few records, or is likely to attract more than a handful of searches simultaneously, you should implement a smarter solution like [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) or implement an external search engine like [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Amazon CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/)  and the like - relational databases like MySQL on their own just aren't good at messy searching nor were they ever meant to be.

As for this remark:

> I normally used POST for search bars but I fancy giving GET a go it
>   looks more user friendly to me.

This isn't really the good argument to choose. As a rule:

- GET is for repeatable requests, that the user can F5 on as much as they want.
- POST is for non-repeatable requests, that are usually considered harmful if (overly) repeated.

If your name is Google and you have a gazillion servers all over the world, use GET. If you already know your search has bad performance, stick with POST and don't tempt the lions.

Comment: dremweaver picks up an error with $searchFields = ['name', 'cats', 'sub_cats', 'desc', 'brand'];   however the browser doesn't, does this matter

Comment: You shouldn't code in Dreamweaver, get a good PHP IDE like [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). Since it's a dedicated and well supported PHP IDE it does actually understand [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), a feature introduced nearly 2 years ago in March 2012 with PHP 5.4. I'm actually surprised it only complains about that and not the anonymous function that was introduced in PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would speed things up (you would have to test on your data).  However, the following is an alternative with only one comparison:

```
WHERE concat_ws('|', name, cats, sub_cats, desc, brand) LIKE '%$enc%'
```

Because your `like` has a wildcard at the beginning, the query does not use regular indexes.  So this version should not slow things down much, if at all.

The answer to your performance problem, though, may be a full text index.

Comment: I highly doubt it would speed things up - you're still causing a table scan, and exactly the same amount of string searching per row. If it's faster at all it wouldn't be much of a difference, and probably vary per hour of day.